# Как сделать чтоб кнопка отображалась поверх tabcontrol и tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать чтоб кнопка отображалась поверх tabcontrol и tabpage

Comment: Скрин бы не помешал. Что есть сейчас и как хотите чтобы было. В зависимости от того, какой расклад сейчас, решение может быть разное.

Answer (score 1):

Что конкретно не получается?

```
int buttonIndex = Controls.GetChildIndex(button1);          //2
int tabControlIndex = Controls.GetChildIndex(tabControl1);  //1

//меняем местами
Controls.SetChildIndex(button1, tabControlIndex);
```

или используйте

```
button1.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Vasilyev Вышла Ошибка: "Дополнительные сведения: 'child' не является дочерним элементом управления этого родительского элемента".

Comment: Какой элемент является родительским для Button и TabControl? Контролы на форму динамически добавляете? Приведите Ваш код, пожалуйста.

Comment: this.Controls.Add(this.buttonHide);

Comment: partial class Form1
    {  private void InitializeComponent()
        { тут создаю кнопку}}

Comment: Где создается TabControl? Добавляете ли Вы его в Controls формы? Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, приведя код создания buttonHide, TabControl и метод, в котором Вы хотите переместить кнопку на передний план.Из комментария не понятно, что и где происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте методы [SetChildIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex(v=vs.110).aspx) или [BringToFront](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Не получается так

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь что и кнопка, и tabControl лежат непосредственно на форме, и при этом кнопка лежит выше. Это можно сделать с помощью Menu → View → Other Windows → Document Outline. В нем должна быть следующая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у вас наблюдается что-то другое (например, button отображен как элемент внутри tabPage1) - поменяйте ее перетягиванием элементов прямо в этом дереве.

После этого кнопку в дизайнере формы лучше не тягать - это автоматом переложит ее внутрь tabPage, и у вас все опять поломается.

Именно для такой же картины, но ситуации когда button1 расположен *ниже* (но не внутри!) tabControl, будет применим код с `BringToFront` - т.к. этот метод переставляет элементы на одном уровне иерархии.