# Как скрыть элемент Tabcontrol с формы Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Как скрыть элемент Tabcontrol с формы Windows form

Comment: Берем контрол, ставим ему свойство `Visible = false`. Не?

Comment: @Dmitry D. А как сделать чтоб кнопка button1 отображалась поверх Tabcontrol или вообще поверх других элементов формы

Comment: Вам не кажется, что это совсем другой вопрос? Кстати, ваш же: [другой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481951/Как-сделать-чтоб-кнопка-отображалась-поверх-tabcontrol-и-tabpage).

Comment: @DmitryD.: Смело пишите в качестве ответа, если не примет, будем поднимать народным голосованием. :)

Comment: @SVD102: Для этого нужно чтобы parent этого контрола не был присвоен. Если тащить из тулбокса в дизайнере, parent автоматически присваевается. Поэтому можно, например, перетащить просто на форму, а потом в коде выставить позицию. Еще вариант - перетащить контрол стрелочками на клавиатуре. Но главный вопрос - а зачем? :)

Comment: @Neolisk Сказано - сделано. :)

Comment: @Neolisk Что нужно выставить в коде? Какую позицию?

Comment: @SVD102: Позицию того элемента, который нужно показать поверх всех. control.[Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) = new Point(x, y). Можно еще сделать control.BringToFront чтоб наверняка. Это ответ на ваш *другой* вопрос. Вам там об этом и так уже написали.

Answer (score 3):

У всех элементов управления есть свойство [`Visible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), унаследованное от их общего предка: `System.Windows.Froms.Control`.
Чтобы скрыть элемент управления, установите в этом его свойстве значение `false`. Например:

```
tabControl1.Visible = false;
```